# get value from controller to form symfony 3

Tags: php, forms, symfony, controller

I don't know why i can't get the value on form from the variable of controller.

My controller:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request,$id){
    $ac = new Usersacademi();
    $form = $this->createForm(UsersacademiType::class,$ac,array('id'=>$id));
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid()){
        $ac->setIdacademicprogram($form->get("idacademicprogram")->getData());
        $ac->setIduser($form->get("iduser")->getData());
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($ac);
        $flush = $em->flush();
    }
    else{
    }


    return $this->render("AppBundle:admin:apteacher.html.twig", array(
        "form" => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

My form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('idacademicprogram', EntityType::class, array(
            "required"=>"required",
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Academicprogram',
            'choice_label' => 'name'
        ))
        ->add('iduser', NumberType::class, array("required"=>"required",
            "data" =>$options["id"],
            "attr"=>array(
            "class" => "form-iduser form-control"
        )));
}
```

And i'm getting this error:

> The option "id" does not exist. Defined options are: "action",
>   "allow_extra_fields", "attr", "auto_initialize", "block_name",
>   "by_reference", "compound", "constraints", "csrf_field_name",
>   "csrf_message", "csrf_protection", "csrf_token_id",
>   "csrf_token_manager", "data", "data_class", "disabled", "empty_data",
>   "error_bubbling", "error_mapping", "extra_fields_message",
>   "inherit_data", "invalid_message", "invalid_message_parameters",
>   "label", "label_attr", "label_format", "mapped", "method",
>   "post_max_size_message", "property_path", "required",
>   "translation_domain", "trim", "upload_max_size_message",
>   "validation_groups".

Comment: What does your UsersacademiType::configureOptions() look like? http://symfony.com/doc/3.3/form/create_custom_field_type.html#defining-the-field-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare an empty array in setDefaultOptions.

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'YourEntity',
        'id' => array(),
    ));
}
```